# GZipStream sum compressing blocks to file

Tags: c#, gzipstream

I make an archiver with block-by-block reading and file compression. I put the compressed block in FileStream.
I am reading the 5 mb block. The problem is that if I compress a pic of 8 mb, then when I pull it out of the resulting archive, its sum-hash does not match the original and it opens pic halfway, and the size is the same... I don’t know what to try. I ask for help.

Read chunk void:

```
private byte[] ReadChunk(int chunkId)
    {
        using (var inFile = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            long filePosition = chunkId * chunkDataSize;
            int bytesRead;

            if (inFile.Length - filePosition <= chunkDataSize)
            {
                bytesRead = (int)(inFile.Length - filePosition);
            }
            else
            {
                bytesRead = chunkDataSize;
            }

            var lastBuffer = new byte[bytesRead];
            inFile.Read(lastBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            return lastBuffer;
        }
    }
```

Compress and write void:

```
private void CompressBlock(byte[] bytesTo)
    {

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (GZipStream gs = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                gs.Write(bytesTo, 0, bytesTo.Length);
            }
            
            byte[] compressedData = ms.ToArray();

            using (var outFile = new FileStream(resultFile, FileMode.Append))
            {
                BitConverter.GetBytes(compressedData.Length).CopyTo(compressedData, 4);
                outFile.Write(compressedData, 0, compressedData.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use BeyondCompare to see the differences between original file and corrupted file.

Comment: If I understood it right, your `chunkDataSize` is 5MB. But when you are writing, you are simplly appending data to the file without any consideration of `chunkDataSize`. `GZipStream` does not guaranty to produce fixed size output even for fixed size input because different data compresses differently. With this information in mind your Read / Write logic does not look consistent.

Comment: @AshutoshRaghuwanshi thanks. So I need to set position after compressing for next chunk to write?

Comment: @jdweng the hex difference comes exactly from the second half. that is, the first chunk is written correctly, but the second is not. Why?

Comment: @Fletchet You are already writing size in the place of timestamp header of `GZipStream`. I would suggest you to use it to jump to next node (linked list kind of logic). So first put a loop which runs `n` times to jump to `n`th chunk and rest of the code can work from there.

Comment: How do you determine when reversing the process where the first half ends and the second half starts?  Your algorithm does not support A + B = C, where A is the first half and B is the second half.  What I recommend is add a byte count before each block when you same results so when you reverse process you can process each block separately.